# how to fix ssh on gcloud vm

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-compute

Earlier today, I tried to connect to my google cloud vm instance via ssh, but I got an error saying:

```
An error occurred while communicating with the SSH server. 
Check the server and the network configuration.
```

I have tried connecting via ssh using my local machine as well as the ssh button next to my vm instance on the gcloud website, but neither are working. The machine starts up without any issues, and the logs don't show any errors. It's just ssh that I'm having issues with.

This became a problem after I stopped and started my instance using the buttons on the google cloud console website. I had stopped and started my machine several times before without any issues.

Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but the vm was created using one of google's tensorflow deep learning vm images. Here's the description of the image:

- Google, Intel® optimized Deep Learning Image: TensorFlow 2.0.0, m42 (with Intel® MKL-DNN/MKL and CUDA 10.0), A Debian based image with TensorFlow (With CUDA 10.0 and Intel® MKL-DNN, Intel® MKL) plus Intel® optimized NumPy, SciPy, and scikit-learn.

Comment: Hi there! This behavior, not being able to SSH to the VM, is quite common when the disk is full. Can you please check [the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output) of your VM and check if it says something about "no space left" ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Just checked the serial console and there is no message saying "no space left". I also increased the storage capacity of the vm from my gcloud console just to be safe, but I'm still unable to connect.

Comment: **1**.  Please go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the `VM instance details` find section **Logs** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)` restart your VM post full log at [hastebin.com](https://hastebin.com) **2**. Make a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of the disk before any changes to protect your data **3**. Try to connect to your instance via serial port as it described in this [guide](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b)

Comment: **4**. Try to follow the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) and update your question with your steps, commands and outputs. **5**. There's no help in increasing disk space at gcloud console only because your should configured in your OS as well accordingly to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_partitions).

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try ssh from another workstation to rule out any firewall stuff in your local system.
Try "gcloud compute ssh" using cloud shell if not done already.
Check if "External IP" is attached and the Firewall is open for port 22 from the internet.

Comment: Just tried from another workstation and its still not working. Cloud shell is still giving the same error above. When I run it in a local shell on a different workstation, the external IP is listed, in the following error message: "Connection closed by <EXTERNAL IP>"

Comment: Could you run a port open test using either TELNET or NC and post the result
Kindly post me the command you tried from cloud shell

Comment: Just ran the test on port 22 using TELNET and its open. The command I was running from the shell was: gcloud compute ssh --zone "us-west1-b"  <INSTANCE NAME> --project <PROJECT NAME>

Comment: ok, could you please post ssh debug. "gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag="-vvv" " output
also, ensure a correct user is set "gcloud auth list"
and what is the output of "curl -H'Metadata-Flavor: Google'  http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/ssh-keys/"